# Paires de verbes voisins, par ex. « cligner » et « clignoter » - est-ce qu'il y a de tels autres?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, suffixes

J'ai constaté que le verbe « **cligner** » veut dire « fermer et rouvrir » , tandis que son cousin « **clignoter** » veut dire « s’éteindre et se rallumer », en parlant d'une lumière.

Le rapport entre ces deux verbes qui s'épellent de façon similaire mais qui ont des sens subtilement distincts me rappelle les suffixes diminutifs des noms.

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres paires ou groupes de verbes qui partagent une racine ainsi que leur fonctionnement grammatical, mais qui diffèrent légèrement en sens?

Comment: Il y a pas mal des verbes formés en ajoutant des préfixes : prendre, comprendre, surprendre, etc

Comment: @RogerVadim C'est vrai mais les différences de sens sont souvent bien plus notables dans le cas d'ajout de préfixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En voici quelques uns :

| base | diminutif |
| --- | --- |
| baiser | baisouiller / baisoter |
| boiter | boitiller |
| bouger | bougeotter |
| chanter | chantonner |
| chercher | cherchouiller |
| cligner | clignoter |
| coucher | couchailler |
| cracher | crachoter |
| danser | dansotter |
| écraser | écrabouiller |
| écrire | écrivailler |
| estamper | estampiller |
| discuter | discutailler |
| fendre | fendiller |
| friser | frisoter |
| glander | glandouiller |
| gratter | grattouiller |
| laver | lavouiller |
| lécher | léchouiller |
| mâcher | mâchouiller |
| manger | mangeouiller / mangeotter |
| marcher | marchotter |
| mordre | mordiller |
| parler | parloter |
| piquer | picoter / piqueter |
| pisser | pissoter |
| pleuvoir | pleuv(i)oter |
| pleurer | pleurnicher |
| riper | ripailler |
| rôder | rôdailler |
| ronfler | ronflot(t)er |
| sauter | sautiller |
| sonner | sonnailler |
| siffler | siffloter |
| sucer | suçoter |
| tacher | tacheter |
| taper | tapoter |
| tâter | tâtonner |
| tirer | tirailler |
| tourner | tournailler |
| tourner (→ tourniquer) | tournicoter |
| toucher | touchotter |
| tousser | toussoter |
| trafiquer | traficoter |
| traîner | traînailler |
| trembler | trembloter |
| tremper | trempouiller |
| voler | voleter |
| vivre | vivoter |

Comment: J'ajouterais  "lier" & "ligoter" ainsi que "friser" & "frisotter". Je me demande si peut être "baiser" (dans le sens d' "embrasser") et "bécoter", ainsi que "revivre" & "ravigoter" pourraient s'ajouter à la liste?   Enfin, les français utilisent quelques fois le verbe "marchoter" au lieu de "marcher" soit en référence à un appareil qui ne fonctionne ("marche") pas très bien où pour décrire l'action de marcher paisiblement, lentement, lors d'une promenade par example.

Comment: @Mbio Je m'étais limité aux verbes en -oter. Je viens d'en rajouter avec d'autres suffixes dont quelques un de ta liste. Je n'ai cependant pas repris ceux dont le lien étymologique n'était pas attesté.